# how to Map rtf file rows to 3 RichTextBox in VB.Net 2010?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

I need to split "richtextbox4 rows" to richtextbox1 take row number 1

richtextbox2 take row number 2

and richtextbox3 take row number 3

so all 3 richtextboxs take a row from "richtextbox4 rows"

Comment: You just asked the same question an hour ago.

Comment: please show me the code with richtextboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count

            If i = 0 Then
                RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                RichTextBox3.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
            ElseIf i = 2 Then
                RichTextBox4.Text = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: great but how to do that with RichTextBox.rtf without RichTextBox.Text